# Image 8-connectivity without excessive branching?

Tags: performance, image-processing

I'm writing a low level image processing algorithm which needs to do alot of 8-connectivity checks for pixels. For every pixel I often need to check the pixels above it, below it and on its sides and diagonals.

On the edges of the image there are special cases where there are only 5 or 3 neighbors instead of 8 neighbors for a pixels. The naive way to do it is for every access to check if the coordinates are in the right range and if not, return some default value.

I'm looking for a way to avoid all these checks since they introduce a large overhead to the algorithm. Are there any tricks to avoid it altogether?

Comment: I have seen the following solution: all processing functions do not check for boundaries and assume that there are always neighbors and there are some functions used to artificially add neighbors before processing. All processing functions work on ROI (region of interest) that works only on parts of images that have neighborhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance-critical code you might do something like the following:

```
process row 0
for r = 1 to M - 2
  process row r, pixel 0
  for c = 1 to N - 2
    process row r, pixel c 
  process row r, pixel N - 1
process row M - 1
```

The bulk of the operations are in the inner loop and are branchless. You just handle the first/last row, and the first/last pixel of each row, as special cases. It makes the code bulkier, but that's the nature of the beast when it comes to optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

If there are suitable values for your algorithm, add a 1-pixel border and only check your original pixel data.

Answer (score 2):

Or, to turn @Roger's suggestion around, ignore the outermost pixel along each border, if this works for you.  In other words, only process the interior pixels of your image.